# Shell program - determine average word length in a file

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell program to determine the average word length in a file. I'm assuming I need to use `wc` and `expr` somehow. Guidance in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your file is ASCII and `wc` can indeed read it...

```
chars=$(cat inputfile | wc -c)
words=$(cat inputfile | wc -w)
```

Then a simple

```
avg_word_size=$(( ${chars} / ${words} ))
```

will calculate a (rounded) integer. But it will be "more wrong" than just the rounding error is: you'll have included all whitespace character in your avarage wordsize as well. And I assume you want to be more precise...

The following will give you some increased precision by calculating the rounded integer from a number that is multiplied by 100:

```
_100x_avg_word_size=$(( $((${chars} * 100)) / ${words} ))
```

Now we can use that for telling the world:

```
 echo "Avarage word size is: ${avg_word_size}.${_100x_avg_word_size: -2:2}"
```

To further refine, we could assume that only 1 whitespace character is separating words:

```
 chars=$(cat inputfile | wc -c)
 words=$(cat inputfile | wc -w)

 avg_word_size=$(( $(( ${chars} - $(( ${words} - 1 )) )) / ${words} ))
 _100x_avg_word_size=$(( $((${chars} * 100)) / ${words} ))

 echo "Avarage word size is: ${avg_word_size}.${_100x_avg_word_size: -2:2}"
```

Now it's your job to try and include the concept of 'lines' into your computations...  :-)

Comment: Small change above. I am writing a shell program.

Comment: use `sed 's/\s//g' to take out whitespace on lines, then subtract `wc -l` to account for newlines. I.e. `l=$(wc -l file);w=$(wc -w file);allc=$(sed 's/\s//g' file | wc -c);c=$((allc-l));echo $c`

Comment: @Kevin: `l=$(wc -l file)` will not work. Because the contents of `l` will not be a number, but a string containing a number and the filename and some whitespace....

Comment: Yes, I used `cat` on purpose... And I skipped the 'lines' topic because the question asked for some *guidance in the right direction* only...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going a completely different route, but I still appreciate the help.

Comment: Note that `wc` considers this to contain 6 words: ^[^ ]*[ -~][^ ]*[ ]= { .. by the way, it is not fabricated data! it is the second line of a real file ... and by the way, the above code gets a *divide by zero error* (when the file has no words)

Answer (score 1):

Update: to show clearly (hopefully) the differenct between `wc` and this method; and fixed a "too-many-newlines" bug; Also added finer control of apostrophes in word endings .

If your want to consider a `word` as being a `bash word`, then using `wc` alone is fine.
However if you want to consider a `word` as word in a spoken/written language, then you can't use `wc` for the word parsing.

Eg.. `wc` considers the following to contain **1** word (of size average = 112.00),
wheras the script belows shows it to contain **19** words (of size average = 4.58)

```
"/home/axiom/zap_notes/apps/eng-hin-devnag-itrans/Platt's_Urdu_and_classical_Hindi_to_English_-_preface5.doc't"
```

Using *Kurt's* script, the following line is shown to contain **7** words (of size average = 8.14),
wheras the script presented below shows it to contain **7** words (of size average = 4.43) ...`बे` = 2 chars

```
"बे  = {Platts} ... —be-ḵẖẉabī, s.f. Sleeplessness:"
```

So, if `wc` is your flavour, good, and if not, something like this may suit:

```
# Cater for special situation words: eg 's and 't   
# Convert each group of anything which isn't a "character" (including '_') into a newline.  
# Then, convert each CHARACTER which isn't a newline into a BYTE (not character!).  
# This leaves one 'word' per line, each 'word' being made up of the same BYTE ('x').  
# 
# Without any options, wc prints  newline, word, and byte counts (in that order),
#  so we can capture all 3 values in a bash array
#  
# Use `awk` as a floating point calculator (bash can only do integer arithmetic)

count=($(sed "s/\>'s\([[:punct:]]\|$\)/\1/g      # ignore apostrophe-s ('s) word endings 
              s/'t\>/xt/g      # consider words ending in apostrophe-t ('t) as base word + 2 characters   
              s/[_[:digit:][:blank:][:punct:][:cntrl:]]\+/\n/g 
              s/^\n*//; s/\n*$//; s/[^\n]/x/g" "$file" | wc))
echo "chars / word average:" \
      $(awk -vnl=${count[0]} -vch=${count[2]} 'BEGIN{ printf( "%.2f\n", (ch-nl)/nl ) }')
```

Comment: A character, when talking about words, means a printable visible character, as used in someone's native alphabet; eg: `ळ` is a character in the Devanagari script; it uses 3 bytes in UTF-8 (the standard unix/linux encoding system is UTF-8).  `ā` is a character in the Extended Latin script; it uses 2 bytes in UTF-8.   `wc` does count *characters* correctly, but (just by the way) `tr` has no concept of characters, tr only  understand bytes.. Multi-byte characters are a surprisingly major problem! especially when converting between systems like UTF-8 and and UTF-16

Comment: Why shouln't digits form part of a word in your book? Why should each digit be replaced by a newline?!

Comment: You can tweak it as you like!  That is one reason I posted this answer.  it gives *you* control.  It depends on whether you mean *dictionary* words, or *coputer programming jargon* words, etc..

Comment: Well, **your** method results in `characters per word average:  29.8769` for one of my example files. **My** method results in `"Avarage word size is: 11.62"`. I trust my result more, having looked at my original file....   ;-)

Comment: I'd be interested to see that file, because for a 7842 word file I get very similar results. Your versio: 4.62 .. my version: 4.0776 .. the differences would be because of the different parsing methods.

Comment: Update... I just tried a Devanagari/Arabic/Ascii/Extended Latin file, and got quite a shock! (0.9 characters per word) , but then  I realized it was encoded in UTF-16 (exactly the trap I mentioned in my first commemnt :(....  After re-encoding it to UTF-8, your method gives: 6.48; mine gives: 4.13 ...  This has got me really interested now :) .. It is a big(-ish) file (for text) 2.4 MB, 32,011 lines

Comment: Of course, the differences for that file (29 vs. 11) are rooted in the different parsing methods. What else? Mine wasn't a typical text file, but the output of this command: `gs -o /dev/null -sDEVICE=png256 -c "currentpagedevice {exch ==only ( ) print == } forall" | sort`

Comment: I've fixed a 'too-many-newlines' bug, though significant differences can still appear, as I've shown in my updated answer.